# Generic detail view ProductListView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf

Tags: python, django

can someone help me found the mistake with my code? I'm studing Django that's why can be possible that i made some stupid mistake or i forgot to write something.
In my homepage i would like just to show a list of products but i immediately got this error!

I already checked the topics here in SoF but i didn't found a solution.

**Models:**

```
from django.db import models

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer,
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    related_name="products")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    shipping_cost = models.FloatField()
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is my **views**:

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

from .models import Product, Manufacturer


class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product
    template_name = "products/product_detail.html"


class ProductListView(DetailView):
    model = Product
    template_name = "products/product_list.html"
```

and this is the **urls** of my app:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ProductListView, ProductDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ProductListView.as_view(), name="product-list"),
    path('products/<int:pk>/', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name="product-detail"),
]
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your `ProductListView` inherits from a <s>`DetailView`</s>, not a `ListView`. You should inherit from a `ListView`:

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

# …

class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = "products/product_list.html"
```

The reason you got this error is because by default, a `DetailView` will need a primary key, or slug to select a specific item from the `QuerySet`. For a `ListView` that is of course not the case.

Comment: I was sure i made something stupid!! :) Thanks @Willem Van Onsem